# SQLalchemy merge two queries from same table

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need to query the total sales & guest for each Store for yesterday and the same day last year with the goal to be able to display in a table using jinja2.
I currently have two queries with a Union...

```
    this_year = db.session.query(Sales.name,
                                   func.sum(Sales.sales).label('total_sales'),
                                   func.sum(Sales.guests).label('total_guests')
                                   ).filter(Sales.date >= start_day,
                                            Sales.date <= end_day
                                            ).group_by(Sales.name)


    last_year = db.session.query(Sales.name,
                                   func.sum(Sales.sales).label('total_sales'),
                                    func.sum(Sales.guests).label('total_guests')
                                   ).filter(Sales.date >= start_day_ly,
                                           Sales.date <= end_day_ly
                                            ).group_by(Sales.name)


    daily_table = this_year.union(last_year).all()
```

... but it gives me a list like so:

```
STORE 1, SALES, GUESTS
STORE 1, SALES_LY, GUESTS_LY
STORE 2, SALES, GUESTS
STORE 2, SALES_LY, GUESTS_LY
ETC,,
```

what i want is:

```
STORE 1, SALES, SALES_LY, GUESTS, GUESTS_LY
STORE 2, SALES, SALES_LY, GUESTS, GUESTS_LY
```

```
class Sales(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'Sales'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.String(64))
    daypart = db.Column(db.String(64))
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    sales = db.Column(db.Integer)
    guests = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

data:
|id|date|daypart|name|sales|guests|
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|14896| 2021-11-22| Dinner| STORE 1|    11250.05|   288|
|14897| 2021-11-22| Lunch|  STORE 1|    9250.25|    157|
|14898| 2021-11-22| Dinner| STORE 2|    5764.95|    169|
|14899| 2021-11-22| Lunch|  STORE 2|    5856.25|    168|
|14900| 2021-11-22| Dinner| STORE 3|    9186.7| 320|
|14901| 2021-11-22| Lunch|  STORE 3|    7521.0| 175|

This data goes back several years.
I looked at GROUP_BY, SUBQUERY, CASE, JOIN but have not found a solution that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `with_entities`, and use `and_`

```
this_year = db.session.query(Sales)
            .filter(and_(Sales.date >= start_day, Sales.date <= end_day))
            .with_entities(
                Sales.name.label('name'),
                func.sum(Sales.sales).label('total_sales'),
                func.sum(Sales.guests).label('total_guests')
            )
            .group_by(Sales.name)

last_year = db.session.query(Sales)
            .filter(and_(Sales.date >= start_day_ly,Sales.date <= end_day_ly))
            .with_entities(
                Sales.name.label('name'),
                func.sum(Sales.sales).label('total_sales'),
                func.sum(Sales.guests).label('total_guests')
            )
            .group_by(Sales.name)

daily_table = this_year.union(last_year).all()
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond.  After posting, i found a work around by moving "all()" to this_year & that_year, making them a list and using pandas to merge the lists into a dataframe, which worked.  I tried your code and it did exactly want i wanted in slightly less code.  Which would be more efficient?